# How to Group and Merge key with array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have list of json value that I need to group according to loc (Location) which has elements of date.

```
{
        "2":[
          {
             "loc":2,
             "date":{
                "2020-08-09":"2790.0"
             }
          },
          {
             "loc":2,
             "date":{
                "2020-08-10":"402.0"
             }
          },
          {
             "loc":2,
             "date":{
                "2020-08-11":"522.0"
             }
          }
       ],
       "12":[
          {
             "loc":12,
             "date":{
                "2020-08-10":"765.0"
             }
          }
       ],
       "13":[
          {
             "loc":13,
             "date":{
                "2020-08-11":"135.0"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

**My rails code that I use map and create new object format**

```
 result = @weekly_sales_chart.map{ |k| 
       { 
         loc: k['location_id'],
           date: { k['date']=>k['total']} ,
       
          }
       }
  respond_with  result.group_by { |h| h[:loc]}.map{|f, d| d.inject(:merge)}
```

**Output: (It only group date only one)**

```
[
   {
      "loc":2,
      "date":{
         "2020-08-11":"522.0"
      }
   },
   {
      "loc":12,
      "date":{
         "2020-08-10":"765.0"
      }
   },
   {
      "loc":13,
      "date":{
         "2020-08-11":"135.0"
      }
   }
]
```

**Desired Result: Loc is Group with the same loc value and merge all date under this loc object**

```
 [
   {
      "loc":2,
      "date":{
         "2020-08-09":"2790.0",
         "2020-08-10":"402.0",
         "2020-08-11":"522.0"
      }
   },
   {
      "loc":12,
      "date":{
         "2020-08-10":"765.0"
      }
   },
   {
      "loc":13,
      "date":{
         "2020-08-11":"135.0"
      }
   }
]
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian Palma I already resolved my issue.  I refactor your sample code that helps me to produce my desired result:

```
 result = @weekly_sales_chart.map{ |k| 
       { 
         loc: k['location_id'],
           date: { k['date']=>k['total']} ,
       
          }
       }

       data =  result.group_by { |h| h[:loc]}
       respond_with data.map{|_, location_id | location_id.reduce({}) { |result, loc_id|
          result.merge(loc_id) do |key, oldval, newval|
            key == :date ? oldval.merge(newval) : oldval
              end
      } }
```

Thanks for helping out

Comment: Your example is already grouped by "loc", do you need to group it again? Also `map {  |_, value| }` is almost the same as using transform_values.